# Summing $\sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} \frac{n}{n+ 1}(x^{n + 1})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms

Assuming $x < 1$, what is the sum of, $$\sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} \frac{n}{n+ 1}(x^{n + 1}) = \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{2}{3}x^3 + \frac{3}{4}x^4  + \frac{4}{5}x^5 + \dots $$

My attempt so far:

$$ln(1 - x) = -x - \frac{(-x)^2}{2} + \frac{(-x)^3}{3} - \frac{(-x)^4}{4} \dots $$

$$= -x - \frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^4}{4} \dots $$

$$\Longrightarrow -ln(1 - x) - x = \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x^4}{4}\dots $$

Here things begin to grind to a halt.

If I were to multiply the right hand side by $(1 + x + x^2 + \dots)$ I'd have,

$$(1 + x + x^2 + \dots)(\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x^4}{4} + \dots) = \frac{x^2}{2} + (\frac{x^3}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3}) + (\frac{x^4}{2} + \frac{x^4}{3} + \frac{x^4}{4}) + \dots $$

This is obviously wrong, but it feels like the sort of thing to do. If only the fractions of the RHS of the above equation were$ \frac{1}{2} + (\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3})  + (\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4}) + \dots$ I'd be done.

I've also tried adding or multiplying by $e$ or multiples thereof, but summing fractions of factorials doesn't seem to be fruitful. Have tried adding other log series to this sum, but so far no amount of grouping gives me one additional fraction for each term.

Any hints? Solving this without resorting to any techniques from calculus is part of the challenge.

Comment: As I mentioned at the end, no derivatives, no integration. This problem assumes algebra only.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+of+n%2F%28n%2B1%29+*+x%5E%28n%2B1%29+from+1+to+inf pretty interesting end answer

Comment: Hint: use the fact that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n = -\frac{x}{x-1}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that
$$ \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{n}{n + 1}x^{n + 1} = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty x^{n + 1} - \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{x^{n + 1}}{n + 1}. $$
The first sum looks like a geometric series and the second sum looks like the power series of a logarithmic function. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, got it. Always seems obvious after the fact. Thank you for the assist.

Answer (score 1):

Let's just play around with the coefficients. You say you want no use of differentiation or integration, but I find that strange since you have to arrive at the series for $\ln$ *somehow*...

$$\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{n\color{red}{+1-1}}{n+1}x^{n+1}=\sum_{n\ge1}x^{n+1}-\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{n+1}x^{n+1}=\sum_{n\ge2}x^n-\sum_{n\ge1}(-1)^n\frac{(-x)^n}{n}+x$$

Can you continue?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As the book I'm working out of clearly shows, you can arrive at the series for $ln$ using nothing more than the binomial theorem and the notion of limits to infinity. At any rate, I will mull over what you've started here.

Comment: @RTF But how do you *define* $\ln$? :) I've never seen an acceptably rigorous definition that didn't involve calculus at *some* stage (except for the cheating technique of $\ln x:=[\text{series}]$)

Comment: Not a mathematician, so maybe this won't be a perfectly satisfactory but my best attempt at summarizing in < 500 characters is: Binom expansion of $( 1+ \frac{1}{n})^{nx} \dots \longrightarrow \dots = (1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!} + \dots)^x$ as $n \to +\infty$. Define $(1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2!} + \dots)$ as $e$ and $ln$ as log to base $e$. To get exponential series write $a = e^x \longrightarrow c = ln(a)$. Therefore, $a^x = 1 + xln(a) + \frac{x^2(lna)^2}{2!} + \dots$. To get $ln$ series write $1 + x$ for $a$ in $a^y$ expansion. Now expand $(1 + x)^y$ by binomial and equate coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

$$\frac n{n+1}x^{n+1}=\int n x^n\,dx=x\int\left(x^n\right)dx$$

and with this, for $\;|x|<1\;$ :

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac n{n+1}x^{n+1}=\int\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n\right)dx=\int\left(x\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\right)'\right) dx$$

Observe that the middle term can be taken as sum from $\,n=0\;$ ...

and now:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac1{1-x}\implies\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\right)'=\frac1{(1-x)^2}$$

and thus ( again, for $\;|x|<1\;$):

$$\int\left(x\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\right)'\right) dx=\int\frac x{(1-x)^2} dx=\int\left(-\frac1{1-x}+\frac1{(1-x)^2}\right) dx=\log(1-x)+\frac1{1-x}+C$$

Comment: Hi my friend ! Long time no see you here

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici   Mon cher ami! I don't know where you're from but I shall be in Paris next september. Anyway, hope you're fine !